# Invoking a static method that's in a different class, that calls a protected method inside that same class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Maybe its just because I'm tired and have been working all day, or maybe it's because I just don't really have a firm grasp on PHP classes as I thought I did. But anyways. Here's my problem.

I'm calling a static method using this line of code seen below, from the file `ServiceProvider.php`.

```php
use webdevhacks\LaraBlog\Resources;
public function boot() {
Resources::load();
}
```

Now inside of my resources class named `Resources.php`, I have the following bit of code.

```php
namespace webdevhacks\LaraBlog;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use webdevhacks\LaraBlog\LaraBlog;


class Resources {

    // Load Resources
    public static function load() {
        // Load Package Routes
        return $this->loadRoutes();
    }

    // Load Routes
    protected function loadRoutes() {
        return Route::group($this->routeConfiguration(), function() {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php');
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Using $this when not in object context

Now, the end goal is for me to be able to load multiple resources using the static method `load()`. I want to have methods inside of `Resources.php` that load multiple resources such as views, migrations, routes, etc.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php - `the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static`

Comment: So, how would you write the code to execute loadRoutes() method inside of the static function?

Comment: Question: why are you using a static method to begin with? Why not create an object in the `boot` method and then follow that through?

Comment: @waterloomatt how would I do that? I'm very new to Service Providers in Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're trying to call an instance method from a static method.

Static methods are not associated with a particular instance of your class; instead *they are associated only with the class itself*. This is why you can call static methods without actually creating an instance of a class.

Instance methods, on the other hand, can only be called on an actual instance of the class, and for that reason, they can never be called from static methods (unless the static method actually creates an instance).

In order for this to work, loadRoutes, loadRoutesFrom, and routeConfiguration would all need to also be static methods. If you want to be able to change the routeConfiguration, you might be better off passing it as a parameter to loadRoutes. Something like this:

```
class Resources {
    // Load Resources
    public static function load($configuration) {
        // Load Package Routes
        return Resources::loadRoutes($configuration);
    }

    // Load Routes
    protected static function loadRoutes($configuration) {
        return Route::group($configuration, function() {
            Resources::loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense now and has gotten me on the right track! I think I got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it!